# Alexa impossible to retrieve slot.value

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, alexa-voice-service, alexa-slot

I have two questions if I may. But let me first put you in the context:
I have Intent1 with slot channel. If I try to retrieve channel.value then it works just fine.
I have Intent2 with slot RadioNumber. If I try to retrieve RadioNumber.value then it doesn't work.
Int the console when I try

```
          *console.log(RadioNumber.value)*
```

in the intent2 function it gives

```
          Cannot read property value of undefined
```

I have noticed that The request.Json of the two intents are different which doesn't make any sense since I implemented the two slots in the exact same way! So that is my first question. 
[image]

[image]

As you may have noticed RadioNumberSlot has an extra :

```
      "values": [  
                                {  
                                    "value": {  
                                        "name": "hot",  
                                        "id":  
       "27369b3bf4483e8dcfd85ba9a39a947f"  
                                    }  
                                }  
                            ]
```

It is usually easy for me to manipulate the slot.value. And I do not seem to understand what seems to be the issue with this particular slot/intent.
So please, if you have noticed what might be causing the issue, help me :)

Comment: Can you update your question with actual JSON rather than a screenshot. Also include some of your code. The "extra" part you mentioned is for Entity Resolution when you work with synonyms.

Comment: Please provide the JSON schema of your skill. Look for **JSON Editor** in your Alexa Skill Builder.